# System.Drawing.Pen - lines disappear when Labels are placed on Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, system.drawing

I want to draw TextBoxes/Labels on my form in code and connect them with lines - based on data that I have stored in a datatable ("treedata"). If I use the following code everything works fine:

```
    For i = 0 To treedata.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim tb As New TextBox

        hor = treedata.Rows(i)(11)
        vern = ver + 120 * treedata.Rows(i)(4)

        tb.Text = "sometext"
        tb.Location = New Point(hor, vern)

        Form8.Controls.Add(tb)

        posofmodif = treedata.Rows(i)(10)
        vero = treedata.Rows(i)(6)

        Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Green)
        Dim formGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics

        myPen.SetLineCap(LineCap.RoundAnchor, LineCap.ArrowAnchor, DashCap.Flat)
        formGraphics = Form8.CreateGraphics()
        formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, Convert.ToSingle(posofmodif), Convert.ToSingle(vero), Convert.ToSingle(hor), Convert.ToSingle(vern))

        myPen.Dispose()
        formGraphics.Dispose()

    Next
```

However I would like to use labels instead of TextBoxes because it makes no sense to use heavier TextBoxes in this case. But when I simply replace

```
Dim tb As New TextBox
```

by

```
Dim tb As New Label
```

the labels do appear on the Form as expected but the lines connecting them appear only for a moment and then turn invisible.

I first thought that the problem might be caused by labels being over or below the lines but even when I make sure that no line is crossing any label it happens.

Does anyone have an idea what I could do to avoid this?

Comment: Where are you doing the drawing?  If you aren't already doing so, try doing it in the Form.Paint event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:  `Form8.CreateGraphics()`.  That method is volatile, as it creates a `Graphics` instance that does not survive the scope in which it's used.

You need to be using the `Paint` event for whatever control on which you intend to draw.  The form, the label...whatever that is.  The `Paint` event provides a `Graphics` object for you to use, and it gets called whenever the drawing needs to be refreshed.

Because the event fires frequently, you need to be mindful of what you do there.  Heavy lifting in a `Paint` handler can slow an app down considerably.

Comment: Thank you - I hadn't used the paint event so far but just another Sub to draw. Using the Paint event it works....now I just have to figure out how to elegantly pass my datatable to the eventhandler (instead of just setting it public)